# How do I find sample size from large sample with known proportion?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, estimation

I came across this question in my stats book in the Estimation chapter and I can quite figure it out.

The question in book is as follows:

> The proportion of European men who are red-green colour-blind is 8%. How large a sample would need to be selected to be 95% certain that it contains at least this proportion of red-green colour-blind men?

I have tried equating the width of the confidence interval with the proportion that is 8%, but it doesn't seem to work. Does anybody know how to go about this question?

Comment: https://www.qualtrics.com/experience-management/research/determine-sample-size/ Is this what you are looking for or am I missing something?

Comment: @Steven01123581321 The problem with that is that you'll be $95\%$ confident that the proportion will be close to $8\%$, but half the time, it will more than $8\%$ and half the time if will be less than $8\%$.

Comment: @saulspatz ah yes, now I see where the question differs from what I was thinking it was. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a something of a trick question.  Since only $8\%$ of men in the population are color-blind, and we expect the sampled proportion to be normally distributed about the mean, there's really no way to be $95\%$ confident that $8\%$ of the sample will be colored blind, except by sampling the whole population, or perhaps very close to the whole population.

To take a concrete example, suppose the population size is $100$ and there are $8$ color-blind individuals.  With a sample size of $90$, in order for at least $8\%$ of the sample to be color-blind, we need to sample all the color-blind men.  The probability that this happens is $$\frac{\binom{92}{82}}{\binom{100}{90}}\approx.41655$$

That said, I'm not sure exactly what answer is expected.

Comment: Well I don't really know. The answer is 45. I think the answer can be found by doing equating, $k\sqrt{\frac{\widehat{p}(1-\widehat{p})}{n}}=0.08$, I just don't understand why. Do you understand why this is done?

Comment: @mikejacob That makes no sense to me, for the reasons I've stated.  Are you certain you've stated the problem correctly?

Comment: Yes, the question is written correctly. Your answer does not seem correct to me as it is a decimal, whilst the question asks for how large a sample. So in this case 45 makes more sense than your 0.41655. I just don't understand why the method used to find 45 is the correct one. Why equate half of the confidence interval's width with 0.08??

Comment: @mikejacob The $.41655$ should be compared to $95\%$.  What my example shows is that with a sample size of $90$, we only have $41\%$ confidence that at least $8\%$ of the sample will be color-blind, for a population of $100$.